# Adding up conditions in case clase without modifying where clause

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following:

```
+---------+-------------+---------+
| revenue | bill_amount | invoice |
+=========+=============+=========+
| 2       | 1           | sad     |
+---------+-------------+---------+
| 2       | 5           | null    |
+---------+-------------+---------+
| 5       | 7           | null    |
+---------+-------------+---------+
| 5       | 2           | asdf    |
+---------+-------------+---------+
```

and I have a query I want to do with a case condition (this is part of a bigger query so I can't modify the where clause of the condition, all the logic should be on the CASE)

I need to sum all revenue amounts and bill_amounts in which the invoice is not null, so from my example table, only first and last row. and from this, If the sum of revenue is higher than the sum of bill_amount (where invoice not null)  I have to do the sum(revenue) - sum(bill_amount)

I've tried to express it the following way:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
               WHEN SUM(CASE
                            WHEN Invoice IS NOT NULL
                            THEN Revenue
                            ELSE 0
                        END) > SUM(CASE
                                       WHEN Invoice IS NOT NULL
                                       THEN Bill_Amount
                                       ELSE 0
                                   END)
               THEN(SUM(CASE
                            WHEN Invoice IS NOT NULL
                            THEN Revenue
                            ELSE 0
                        END) - SUM(CASE
                                       WHEN Invoice IS NOT NULL
                                       THEN Bill_Amount
                                       ELSE 0
                                   END))
               ELSE 0
           END) AS Total
FROM Table
Where Conditions
```

but I'm getting and error saying  "nested group function without GROUP BY"
is there a way I can do this better?

I feel that my approach is dumb, but I'm not coming up with a better wayof achieving this calculation (the entire query has a lot of other case statements so I can't modify the where clause or will impact the other cases)

Comment: You don't want to disturb WHERE clause, ok. But what about GROUP BY? Can you use it?
If not, then I think you can't SUM without using GROUP BY.

Comment: uhm.. would a group by affect the other results? I have to try it. thank you

Comment: No, it won't...